# Akka Http: Calling TypedActor.context outside of a TypedActor implementation method

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-http

I'm trying to build akka http client, by using this example [Test akka http client](https://medium.com/@pwdd/testing-akka-http-clients-59fa2d0545c1)

This is my code:

```
trait HttpServer {
   def sendAndReceive: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse]
}

trait ApiHandler extends HttpServer {
  implicit def as: ActorSystem
  override def sendAndReceive: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] =
     Http().singleRequest(_)
 }

trait Api {
    this: ApiHandler =>

    implicit def as: ActorSystem
    implicit def mat: Materializer
    implicit def ec: ExecutionContext

    def request(httpRequest: HttpRequest): Future[HttpResponse] = {
      sendAndReceive(httpRequest).flatMap { response =>
         response.status match {
           case StatusCodes.OK => Future.successful(response)
           case _ => throw new RuntimeException ("error")
        }
      }
    }
  }

  class ApiImpl() (implicit val as: ActorSystem, val mat: Materializer, val ec: ExecutionContext) extends Api with ApiHandler {
       def request: Future[HttpResponse] = {
       val httpRequest = ???
       request(httpRequest)
       }
   }
```

And this is how I call request method:

```
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("system")
  implicit val executionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val api = new ApiImpl()
  api.request
```

I receive the following error in place, where trait Api request calls sendAndReceive-method (in this line:  sendAndReceive(httpRequest).flatMap { response => ):

```
Calling TypedActor.context outside of a TypedActor implementation method!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what version of Akka are you using?

Comment: akka-actor 2.5.23      akka-stream   2.5.9   akka-http   10.1.9

Comment: it seems to be ok. Can you add the details of "details of behaviour", I asume that your request is something like  Get("https://akka.io")

Comment: Emiliano Martinez, I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
trait HttpServer {
    def sendAndReceive: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse]
  }

  trait ApiHandler extends HttpServer {
    implicit def as: ActorSystem

    override def sendAndReceive: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] =
      Http().singleRequest(_)
  }

  trait Api {
    this: ApiHandler =>

    implicit def as: ActorSystem

    implicit def mat: Materializer

    implicit def ec: ExecutionContext

    def request(httpRequest: HttpRequest) = {
      sendAndReceive(httpRequest).flatMap {
        response =>
          response.status match {
            case StatusCodes.OK => Future.successful(response)
            case _ => throw new RuntimeException("error")
          }
      }
    }
  }

  class ApiImpl()(implicit val as: ActorSystem, val mat: Materializer, val ec: ExecutionContext) extends Api with ApiHandler {
    def request2 = {
      val httpRequest = Get("https://akka.io")
      request(httpRequest)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("system")
    implicit val executionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

    val api = new ApiImpl()
    api.request2.map(println(_))
  }
```

with versions:

```
val akkaVersion = "2.6.7"
val akkaHttpVersion = "10.1.12"
```

Works properly:

```
HttpResponse(200 OK,List(Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2023 12:19:39 GMT, Connection: keep-alive, Last-Modified: Tue, 17 Jan 2023 13:53:07 GMT, Vary: Accept-Encoding, CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC, Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=GZ7HZLwXVyB%2BXRzpcYY4A%2BjpGd0h0S8EsbSRWwMm0b8UbQrnqWpmB8e%2FFEYkNsZUVUdCWboRsWP%2B0aC6YJETfHGZU%2FU%2BFyhetR6%2FA8527KxVKfuGTjpr0Chp"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}, NEL: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}, Server: cloudflare, CF-RAY: 7953d5d82a3c384d-MAD, alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400),HttpEntity.Chunked(text/html),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
```